# JMS Listener Not Picking Up Message From the Queue

Tags: jms

I am planning to do code change for an existing application which has a JMS listener.

To test whether the listener works on my local server, I deploy the application to my localhost and shutdown other containers that running the same application.

But my local listener won't pick up any message. It is confirmed that other containers work fine and can pick up and process new messages in the queue.

Can you think of any possible cause of this?

Answer (score 3):

Way too general, too many missing points...but some things to look at:

- if the message queue is on a different server, can you ping it from the local device?  could be that development environment can't see production server, perhaps
- does a netstat -n show the correct port number, you should see a remote port with the port on which the message provider is listening itself
- can you verify that the messaging provider sees you as a consumer?  I use activemq, I can look at the management console, dive into a specific queue, and view active consumers, most providers will have something similar
- are you running in an identical environment?  Running a listener in a JEE environment where the queue is a jndi reference might be different running in a debugger where you need the actual queue name
- any JMS filtering going on, where the filter for your local envionrment doesn't match up with what's already on the queue?
- any transaction manager stuff that may be getting in the way?

Again, just throwing stuff to see what sticks to the wall, but these are the really obvious things.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Scott for answering my question.

I finally find that Eclipse somehow created another container and my listener was deployed to it. That's why I cannot find it working in my current container.